# How to install Open-Source license #dotnetbrowser

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I have an Open-Source license for DotNetBrowser, but I'm hitting an exception whenever I use the WinFormsBrowserView because I'm failing the license validation:

"DotNetBrowser license check failed: This license can only be used with Bound to type name"

Not entirely sure what that means, or how I go about fixing it.

Comment: have you looked /asked here: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000056943-installing-your-evaluation-licence

Comment: Yes, that worked for the evaluation license, but not the real license.

Comment: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000133949-open-source-licence -  They also provide and email address for questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your licence is bound to your open-source project via a fully qualified type name. Please be sure that it is present in the current assembly.

Comment: Thank you! The type name I put for the license didn't 100% match what was in my root namespace. Fixed that and now it's working perfectly.